# Field at symmetrical axis

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

Whenever we calculate field due to a wire with uniform charge density $\lambda$, we take a point in the middle and choose two elements. We take the field elements and find their components. One of the components cancel each other. Then we add all $x$-components by integration. It comes as $$E=\left(\frac14\pi\epsilon_0\right)\frac{2\lambda}{R^2}$$

I want to ask: Will the value of $E$ still be the same if we measure it somewhere else not at a point of symmetry. I know we do things like this to make the math easier. Will the value of $E$ be same everywhere if we calculate it?

[image: 1]

Like this diagram will help. Why have we chosen a point p like that. We can also take a point anywhere else and try to find it. So why always in the middle? A point somewhere above the P. Will $E$ still be the same?

Comment: Is it an infinite wire ??? And what is lambda ??? What is your source ???

Comment: If it is an infinite wire, then any point is a midpoint.

Comment: Hi, I have made your question clearer by improving formatting and grammar.

Comment: Delete this post..

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  the field had different values (and directions) in different points around the wire.  In points off the symmetry axis the field has y component too.  The integral will be more tedious to calculate so the introductory textbooks use the symmetric case as an example.

Comment: So you mean if we calculate the E at some different point it will come different. But in introductory books we only talk symmetrically. Then why they talk about one point in the centre. Is it so much important

Comment: Also then why the field due to parallel plates stays uniform.

Comment: I already said why. Because otherwise the calculation will be too complicated for the level of the course. In the introductory physics course I teach now most of the students just learned about integrals or they are taking the math course at the same time. So I am more than happy for them to understand the calculation for the simplest case.

Comment: It stays uniform only for infinite plates. Otherwise it is not really uniform.

Comment: I guess you are saying this argument about the presence of y component because you are assuming it as a finite wire. In finite wire configuration only ,this happens

Comment: Of course is about a finite wire.  An infinite wire has no middle and no axis of symmetry perpendicular to the wire. But maybe the OP used these terms inappropriately.

Comment: I think an infinite wire will have infinite centers and axis of symmetry. So at every point we can get the same eqn given above.

Answer (score 0):

You might be misunderstanding why two points are chosen.

I presume this is calculating the E field from a charged wire.

To calculate the field from the wire, you have to add up (integrate) contributions from all parts of the wire, not just A and B. You can add them up one by one and calculate the vector E field from each. If you do, you will add many vectors pointing in many directions. You can do the sum. You will find the sum points directly away from the wire.

Adding pairs of elements just makes the calculation easier. Look at all the pieces of wire in the bottom half. Each piece has a similar piece in the top half. For example, given A, you can find B that is symmetrically placed.

If you calculate the E field from A, you will find the E field from B has the same magnitude because it has the same charge and distance. You will find it is at the same angle as the field from A. From this, you can conclude that the upward component from A is the same size as the downward component from B, and these components cancel.

By the same argument, the upward/downward components from every pair of pieces of wire cancel. You don't have to go to the trouble of calculating these components and adding them to find they are $0$. You know it from this symmetry argument. You conclude the total E field is the of components that point directly away from the wire. The total field must point directly away from the wire.

It doesn't matter where you choose your point P. You can still choose wire pieces in pairs and make the same argument. The field everywhere points directly away from the wire.

If you choose points P$_1$ and P$_2$ the same distance from the wire, you can do the calculation for both. The calculations would be identical at every step. You would get the same answer. This is another symmetry argument. It shows the E field has the same strength at every point the same distance from the wire.

Symmetry arguments are very useful in physics.

Comment: I don’t think the field will be same at points other than point p if it’s a finite wire. At points above and below the p there will be y component  also.

Comment: @cOnnectOrTR12 - True. I had assumed the wire was infinite. The question makes more sense with a finite wire. However, if the wire is long, forces from the pieces near the end are small. Neglecting them doesn't make much difference. For points near the center, the force will be approximately the same.

Answer (score 0):

By "wire", do you mean a line of charge?

If yes, [this should help](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/elelin.html). And if that is the case, your formula for $E$ looks sus.

As you can see in the link, it is not necessary to take the middle point and it is possible to take any point.